# I have a problem with espeak on Raspbian: No module named 'espeak'

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, espeak

---

### Hi! So my problem is: I'm trying to make my Pi 3 speaking, I looked up multiple articles, but none of them could help unfortunately.

---

**My code line:** `from espeak import espeak`
**And I get an error:**
  *File "/home/pi/ttstest.py", line 9, in 

    from espeak import espeak

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'espeak'*

I'm using Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 3.
I have espeak and python-espeak istalled as well.
I used this code in terminal to test the espeak: `espeak "Hello World" 2>/dev/null` It works, I'm hearing the speech.

If someone please could help me, I would be more than grateful! :)

Comment: Have you installed it using Pip? Have you verified that it is being installed to the version of Python you are running here?

Comment: A simple test to check if the version of Python you are running has it installed is to use `python -m pip freeze` and make sure espeak appears in the list.

Comment: Problem solved! Yes, the problem was with the versions, so I downloaded the correct versions, and it's working just fine. Thank you 4 the help! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Method using espeak-python

**Install espeak-python**

`sudo apt install espeak-python`

Then,you can play text as following

```py
from espeak import espeak

espeak.set_voice("en")

espeak.synth("hello")

while espeak.is_playing:
    pass
```

**for more information using this method click [here](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/text-speech-python-espeak)**

## Method using espeak

Alernatively,You can run play using espeak command in python

**install espeak**

`sudo apt install espeak`

Then,you can play text as following

```py
import os
text="this is demo text"
os.system('espeak "'+text+'"')
```

*Here text is wrapped with double quotes because without it the espeak command will only take first word in this case i.e 'this'*

You can also define other arguments as in terminal like speed,voice,word gap etc.

**Example using speed of 200 WPM(words per minute)**

```py
import os
text="this is demo text"
os.system('espeak -s 200 "'+text+'"')
```

**You  may also directly pass string inside double quotes**

```py
import os
os.system('espeak -s 200 "this is demo text"')
```

**for more information using this method click [here](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/text-speech-python-espeak)**